# Приведение типов и списки

Tags: java, generics, полиморфизм

Приветствую. Имеется `List<CellSpec>`, где `CellSpec` - интерфейс. Далее, имеется класс `DefCellSpec`, реализующий вышеупомянутый интерфейс.

Вопрос: почему, когда я передаю в метод: `boolean checkCellSpec (List<CellSpec> specList)` список `List<DefCellSpec>` - компилятор ругается на несоответствие типов?
Притом если передавать один объект - то все ок.

Если создать новый лист по принципу:

```
List<CellSpec> specList = new ArrayList<>(); 
defCellSpecs.forEach(defCellSpec -> specList.add(defCellSpec));
```

и уже его передавать в вышеупомянутый метод, то также все ок, но выглядит как костыль.

Comment: Если коротко - в Java обобщенные типы не поддерживают [ковариантность и контравариантность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). Подробнее - см. ответ в шапке.

Comment: Благодарю. Поиск не нашел эту тему.